# The expression 'u.Roles.AsQueryable().Select(r => r.Name)' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm having an issue while trying to get users with their roles. What I want to do is to get users with their corresponding role but with only the value of the roles such as `roles: ["ADMIN", "USER"]`.

Here's my code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetAll()
{
        return await _context.User.Include(u => u.Roles.Select(r => r.Name)).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: So, what is the result? User with role names but encapsulated in Role class? Maybe you have to create DTO for such result?

Comment: If I use this code User.Include(u => u.Roles).ToListAsync(), I'm able to get users with their roles but I just want the value and not the whole object of the role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Include` is used to load related entities from context via foreign keys or navigation properties.
I think you should rewrite your query in the following way:

```
_context
    .User
    .Select(user => new { user, rolesNames = user.Roles.Select(role => role.Name) }) 
    .ToListAsync()
```

Roles will be included under the hood in the `Select` query. (See @Svyatoslav Danyliv `s comments for more details).

Comment: Guys, `Include` do not work with `Select`, why you put it everywhere?

Comment: @Svytoslav You mean that my code won`t work?

Comment: No, I mean it will work without `Include` because it is ignored after `Select` by EF Core LINQ translator. It is two mutual exclusive operators.

Comment: It seems that you are right. According to this [article](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/querying-in-ef-core.aspx), `Include` is not needed if the `Select` is present. Thank you for the comment. I will edit the answer than.